# Fatal Error when calling static method

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, static-methods, fatal-error

So, here's my situation :

- I'm using CodeIgniter
- I've set up a helper, ('string_helper' under 'DK' folder)
- I've set up the dkString class in dk/string_helper.php

  ```
  static function strInArray($str,$arr)
  {
        foreach ($arr as $item) 
        {
              if (self::inString($str,$item))
                    return true;
        }

        return false;
  }
  ```
- In my controller:

  - I'm loading the helper (`$this->load->helper('dk/string');`)
  - Calling the method (`dkString::strInArray($str,$arr);`)

---

**Note :**

- I've loaded class's static methods residing in a custom helper, like 100 times. So there's nothing wrong with it.
- It doesn't matter whether the function is declared as `static` or not. Normally it works, no matter what.

However, I keep getting the following error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method dkString::strInArray() in
>   /the/path/to/the/caller/file.php on Line XX

Any ideas what might be wrong?

---

```
<?php

/*
 * DK4PHP Library
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2012 by Dr.Kameleon
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published
 * by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 */

if (!class_exists('dkString'))
{
    class dkString
    {
    /**
     * Return number of character in string
     * 
     * @param type $str
     * @return type 
     */

    function characterCount($str)
    {
        return strlen($str); 
    }

    /**
     * Check if str begins with...
     * @param type $str
     * @param type $sub
     * @return type 
     */

    function beginsWith($str, $sub)
    {
        return (substr($str,0,strlen($sub)) == $sub);
    }

    /**
     * Check if str ends with...
     * 
     * @param type $str
     * @param type $sub
     * @return type 
     */

    function endsWith($str, $sub)
    {
        return (substr($str,strlen($str)-strlen($sub)) == $sub);
    }

    /**
     * Check if str contains substring
     * 
     * @param type $sub
     * @param type $str
     * @param type $casesensitive
     * @return type 
     */

    function inString($sub, $str, $casesensitive = false)
    {
        if ($casesensitive)
        return (strstr($str, $sub) == false) ? false : true;
        else
        return (stristr($str, $sub) == false) ? false : true;
    }

    /**
     * Count number of occurences of substring in string
     * 
     * @param type $sub
     * @param type $str
     * @return type 
     */

    function inStringCount($sub, $str) 
    {
        return substr_count($str, $sub);
    }

    /**
     * Convert string to number
     * 
     * @param type $str
     * @param type $check
     * @param type $magic
     * @return type 
     */

    function strtonum($str, $check, $magic)
    {
        $int32Unit = 4294967296;

        $length = strlen($str);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {
        $check *= $magic;
        if ($check >= $int32Unit)
        {
            $check = ($check - $int32Unit * (int) ($check / $int32Unit));

            $check = ($check < -2147483648) ? ($check + $int32Unit) : $check;
        }
        $check += ord($str{$i});
        }
        return $check;
    }

    /**
     * Get index of str in array (check if is contained)
     * 
     * @param type $str
     * @param type $arr 
     */

    function indexInArray($str,$arr)
    {
        foreach ($arr as $index=>$item)
        {
        if (stristr($item,$str))
        {
            return ($index+1);
            break;
        }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Check if str is contained in any of array's elements
     * 
     * @param type $str
     * @param type $arr
     * @return boolean 
     */

    function strInArray($str,$arr)
    {

        foreach ($arr as $item) 
        {
            if (self::inString($str,$item))
                return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
    }
}
?>
```

**UPDATE** :

In my controller, after loading the helper (`$this->load->helper('dk/string');`), I tried :

```
if (class_exists('dkString')) { echo "IT EXISTS<br/>Methods : "; print_r(get_class_methods('dkString')); }
else echo "IT DOESN'T EXIST";
```

The "funny" thing is that the output was :

```
IT EXISTS
Methods : Array ( 
[0] => characterCount 
[1] => beginsWith 
[2] => endsWith 
[3] => inString 
[4] => inStringCount 
[5] => strtonum 
[6] => indexInArray )
```

In a few words : the class IS loaded, and it "sees" ALL methods (except for the last one). Geezz... :/

Comment: @Yazmat Have you spotted one with an answer to this particular issue?

Comment: no you made tow questions with same content but different titles :|

Comment: @Yazmat... Hmmm.. Really??? Ooops, it must have been some issue when I submitted the question... :/

Comment: @Yazmat Just deleted it; thanks for letting me know! ;-)

Comment: You said the folder is `DK`, but you load it with `dk/string`, may this be case-sensitive?

Comment: @DanLee Well, this is just one of CI's weird little things. It doesn't matter at all. All my classes are under `DK` and I'm loading them using `dk/name`. Also, as I mentioned to my other comment, the class seems to have loaded fine (checked with `class_exists`), but the error keeps showing... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a **"public"** function.

```
public static function strInArray($str,$arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (self::inString($str,$item))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Edit:** Its possible that your interpreter can't find the class. Then he can't find the static method. Perhaps you can check with **class_exists** wheather the class is there and loaded.

**Edit2:**
You have to declare you function as static function. Otherwise you cannot call the function with the static operator(::).

http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.static.php

So no one is in chat... but the error message is really clear. You try to call a static function but that function is not a static function so you get the message you get on top.

Otherwise call them as a function over an instance

```
$dkString = new dkString;
$res = $dfString->strInArray();
```

Perhaps its easier when you use internal functions like **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php)** to find a string in an array.

Comment: Nope, still not working; I've tried any possible combination (`static`, `public`, `public static` but nothing... :/ )

Comment: Hmm perhaps your class is not loaded? You could try to include the class before to test.

Comment: If you're not declaring the visibility it falls back to `public`.

Comment: @Stony what do you mean? Check if there's any error when CI loads the helper?

Comment: Its correct but i had the same problem yesterday. This was not working but you're right. But i think then the class is not loaded. Perhaps try to call "class_exists" and check if the class is loaded.

Comment: @Stony Brilliant. Just checked with `class_exists` (just before calling the method). Unfortunately, it **does**. :/

Comment: Very interesting problem. Have you tried to define a second function in your class and call that class to test? And what came when you make a var_dump on that class? Can you see the function?

Comment: Generally in CI, helpers aren't defined in a class - it's usually just a collection of functions in a file.  I'd have to check the code in the loader, but it's possible that CI is doing something odd to the file.

Comment: Maybe you should try using [libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for this kind of task, as the helper seems to expect functions.

Comment: Oh, and @Stony - the default PHP method visibility is public, so adding a public keyword to a method with no visibility specifier won't do anything.

Comment: Hmm But how should it work when you have only a function in a file? You try to call a class "dkString" and then the static function "stringInArray". When you have no class how should this work? @Dan Lee i think this is a better way.

Comment: Just posted the whole `dk/string_helper.php` file contents. It's nothing really complicated itself. It just matters to me since i've got LOADS of helpers. (All of which I can (still) use perfectly though)

Comment: Hmm your functions are not static this is not correct but when they are it should work. Otherwise the file with the class is not loaded over the helper. Perhaps we should make a channel in chat and discuss it there?

Comment: @Stony I'm already using MANY helpers, just like this one, without ever specifying any function as `static`.

Comment: I don't think that this is possbible. When you call a function with the static operator :: then it should be a static function otherwise you can call them normally as instance. http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14915/discussion-between-stony-and-dr-kameleon)