# CodeIgniter - Method not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've opened another question here ( [Fatal Error when calling static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815769/fatal-error-when-calling-static-method) - please, have a look in here if you need to see the exact code), but - after a lot of testing - it seems that the cause is quite weird :

- I'm having lots of helper classes (with static methods in them)
- Intermittently, although the helper loads fine, not ALL functions are visible. (`print_r(get_class_methods('my_class_name'))`) refuses to "see" some methods (even silly/empty ones that I'm adding as a test.

What could be going wrong?

(Could it have to do with any sort of "caching"? (I haven't done anything like that, all development is on a clean CI installation). And if so, how could I solve it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers should just be a file of functions. No classes at all, I would imagine the helper loader is not suited to loading a class at all.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/helpers.html

if you want a class structure please create a library.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html